# Screen doesn't stop refreshing in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this order history screen where you can see order history from firestore. I used `navigator.pushnamed` before with arguments and it's running but I want to put it to `navigator.push` with `materialpageroute`. But when I use it the data shows but it refreshes nonstop.

```dart
void listOrderItems(context) async {
  List orderData = await _checkoutService.listPlacedOrder();

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> args = {'data': orderData};
  for (var items in args['data']) {
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < items['orderDetails'].length; i++) {
      total = total +
          items['orderDetails'][i]['quantity'] *
              items['orderDetails'][i]['price'];
    }
    items['totalPrice'] = total.toString();
  }
  if (!mounted) return;
  setState(() {
    itemList = args['data'];
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem going on, guess it was due to the fact that So what I did was:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
```

> ```
> then
> ```

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => NewPage()))
```